# How to notify using toast each time user change location

Tags: location, toast

I would like to notify user everytime user has changed the location. I have inserted toast inside the `onLocationChanged` but then theres a redline on the `makeText` from `toast.makeText`. It says

```
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (CurrentLocationOverlay, String, int)
```

Then I changed from

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Your current speed is :" +gps.getSpeed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

to `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Your current speed is :" +gps.getSpeed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show().`

Then it told me create `getBaseContext()` method. I even changed it to `getApplicationContext()`. Still the same answer. Even changed it to the class name still the same

public class CurrentLocationOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {

```
GPSTracker gps;



  @Override
  public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    super.onLocationChanged(location);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Your current speed is :" +gps.getSpeed(), 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    // only move to new position if enabled and we are in an border-area
    if (mc != null && centerOnCurrentLocation && inZoomActiveArea(currentPoint)) {
      mc.animateTo(getMyLocation());


    }}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the getApplicationContext and getBaseContext can be used when the class is extending Activity.

Is it possible that you extend Activity and implement MyLocationOverlay?

Answer (score 0):

The specific method needs to extend Activity and then the getApplicationContect can be implemented.